# 'error: package does not exist' React Native Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile

Beginner to Android Studio here...

I've recently coded an application in React Native and compiles fine for iOS.
However, when I open the project in Android Studio, I get the following error:

```
error: package com.kishanjvaghela.cardview does not exist
import com.kishanjvaghela.cardview.RNCardViewPackage;
```

Where should I import this? 
Here is the example of what I see on my screen below.
Thank you.

[errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRInN.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

you must link  react-native-cardview.
that it's already used in your project. it's work without link on ios but not work without link on android .
please check this doc.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cardview